# How to get Milliseconds from group.getMDEntryTime().getValue()

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

How do I get milliseconds from `QuickFix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries`

Here is my code

```
private DateTime getClose(QuickFix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh mds)
{
  DateTime close = new DateTime(0L);
  try
  {
    DateTime last = new DateTime(0L);
    QuickFix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries group = new QuickFix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries();
      for (uint i = 1; i < mds.getNoMDEntries().getValue(); i++)
    {
      group = (QuickFix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries)mds.getGroup(i, group);
      if (group.getMDEntryTime().getValue() != null)
      {

        last = new DateTime(group.getMDEntryDate().getValue().Ticks + group.getMDEntryTime().getValue().Ticks);
        close = ((close.Ticks > last.Ticks) ? close : last);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e) { }
  //return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(close, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
  return close;
}
```

But when I print the close date I get the date with Milliseconds as 000 as shown below

`08/28/2015 18:43:48.000`

Comment: could you do something like this 
`last = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff");` or better yet something as simple as this 
`DateTime.Now.Millisecond`

Comment: I did that. But I do not want to add or show milliseconds from my system for accuracy purposes. I want the exact time stamp that comes with each market data refresh.

Comment: then use the same concept since you are capturing the TimeStamp or DateTime from that object why can't you use string.Format function..

Comment: I did that but I am not getting the millisecond part because in getValue() function it is being dropped. There is a setting to set it true but I am not able to do that. This is NOT pure c# related question. It is a FIX4.4 question.

Comment: I see.. my apologies disregard my previous comments..

Comment: This is the SWIG-wrapped C++ version of QF, isn't it?  (Not QuickFIX/n.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your market data provider isn't sending you milliseconds...

```
last = new DateTime(group.getMDEntryDate().getValue().Ticks + group.getMDEntryTime().getValue().Ticks);
```

Or if they are, you could try getting the MDEntryDate directly, like:

```
group.getField(new StringField("272")).getValue()
```

Comment: @Wapiti You are right. My provider is not sending milliseconds in demo account. So pulled the value from header field 52.

Comment: Glad I could help some. Looks like rupweb helped too. Did you mean to accept his answer or mine? Too bad you can't accept both!

Comment: haha, my guess it was a provider data issue was right first no?! haha... But further, the header of the message is the time the message is sent by the provider, and not the time the provider actually executes on their side. Right? I am not sure it matters though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak this language, but I had a similar problem in python which I solved by looking at the header of the message, rather than elsewhere. Just in case this helps you, see [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823474/quickfix-sendingtime-field-52-dropping-milliseconds).